# android - create folder structured list from downloaded content

Tags: android

I'm in the planning process of an android application. The main purpose, of the app, is to download a folder structure and pdf files from a server and displaying these with the same structure within the app.

I want to display all top level elements on start screen in a list. On click on a top level element a new list view should be visible with all child-element.

As said, the number of elements and structure all depends on the server and needs to be rebuild on every start.

I have been looking some at the expandableListView and the main functionallity is there but it isn't displaying it as I want. Maybe there is some way to configure this to my needs or is there a better way to do this?

Any help and tips would be appreciated.

[expandableListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdGF4.png) - What I want is like this but instead of the dropdown there should be a new list with only the child items.

Comment: Please show code and describe how you want your list to be shown. If it is simply a visual problem, all you should have to do it change the XML

Comment: As said above, I'm just planning and havn't gotten to the part of actually doing it yet. Just need some advice on how I should do it. Added an image above to describe what I want to achieve.

Comment: Then your question is too broad, sorry. StackOverflow is not a tutorial service or recommendation platform. Please update your question once you have a specific problem with the implementation of your plan

Comment: there isn't like I want all fixed to me. I just ask for advice on what I can use to achieve this kind of list, e.g. ExpandableListView.

Comment: Add some code to your question. You have an expandable list, but want one listview to go to another  ListView on an item click. What have you tried to get that?

Comment: Just use a normal listview as the expandable can only expand once and there can be more than two levels. First place the contenr of the base folder in a listview. If the user clicks on a listview item which is a folder open another listview with the contents of that folder. Just as a file explorer does.

Comment: But you have two tasks. The first one is to save all downloaded files in the same file and folder structure as on the server. The second one would be how to make your own file explorer for the download directory. Realise that and and rephrase where you really need help.

Comment: And what is your start screen? Before downloading? Or after downloading?

Comment: @greeapps Thx for the response. Alright, I'm starting the app, it will check against the server for any changes, and download if any. Then I will see the folder structure in a list.